# Prompt on every line

Tags: zsh, zshrc

My prompt currently looks like this*:

```
build_prompt() {
    echo -n "$PWD\n> "
}

setopt promptsubst
PROMPT='%{%f%b%k%}$(build_prompt)'
```

which creates

```
/home/caagr98/
> echo hi
```

However, if I add another line (through vi-mode's `o`, not through line continuations or quotes), it turns into this:

```
/home/caagr98/
> echo hi
echo bye
```

I'd like the `>` to repeat on every line, like this:

```
/home/caagr98/
> echo hi
> echo bye
```

Is this possible?

---

*It doesn't. This is just an extreme simplification.

Comment: Probably not with prompt escapes alone. This sounds like something you would need a custom `zle` widget to accomplish.

Comment: FYI: It is not necessary to put *zsh*'s own prompt code inside `%{…%}`, *zsh* already knows that they have zero-length. And, more importantly, instead of uing a function and `promptsubst` you can just use `%d` to retrieve the current working directory. So just setting `PROMPT=$'%f%b%k%d\n> '` should be sufficient, although it admittedly does not solve the question itself. (Note that `$'…'` is used for quoting in order to evaluate `\n` as newline)

Comment: @Adaephon Yeah, I know that I could use %d in this example, but that function is just something really simple I put together as an example. My real prompt is far more complicated. Not needing `%{%}` for `%f` is good to know, though.